# Struggling to decide if a single-method interface is really a good idea in my case here?

Tags: java, oop, interface, access-modifiers

So I currently have an interface, `Rentable`, intended to be implemented by any object which needs to be, well, rentable, that has three methods:

```
boolean isRented();

void rent();

void terminateRental();
```

Thing is, in classes that implement this interface, the ability to rent and terminate the rental of the implementing object should really be package-private, though obviously I didn't realise this when first writing up my class structure.

A separate rental manager class is providing the public methods to rent a `Rentable` and associate it with another object representing the individual renting it, and this class is the only thing that should really be calling the `rent` and `terminateRental` methods in the `Rentable` object itself. As obviously if other classes can publicly manipulate the rented status of the object without disassociating it from the person renting it, that's a problem.

So really these last two methods from the interface should be package-private, so obviously they need to come out of the interface, but then is having the interface:

```
public interface Rentable {

    boolean isRented();

}
```

... really a good idea or good practice? I've looked up single-method interfaces and when they're a good idea or not but can't find much relating to this kind of situation. It seems slightly wrong to me, although I suppose the fact that it requires an object have a rented status implies methods to change it need to be written, and it could be good for me to support other objects becoming `Rentable` in the future (currently it's just Cars, but potentially other types of vehicles or services could be rented). But I'm just not sure how good practice this is, or if there's some kind of alternative in this situation I'm not seeing?

Comment: Sometimes the situation calls for a zero method interface. In your case, I would say that a single method interface is warranted. What you really want to be able to do is to be able to safely know that the object you have in front of you is rentable, and therefore, your interface, imho, is warranted.

Comment: If an interface is a contract to guarantee certain methods / properties, then a single method interface is probably correct. Unless there is anything else needed in a more generalized way for a class implementing your interface.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently wrong with single-method interfaces (and the standard library contains some, however relevant that may or may not be).  If the only thing you need implementations to guarantee to their clients is the ability to communicate whether they are rented, then the interface you propose is fine.

Note, too, that there is more to an interface than just its methods: interfaces are *bona fide* types.  If you are not using this interface that way -- as the declared type or type parameter of variables, method parameters, and/or return types -- then you really are not getting much out of it.